# Importing GEE feature collection output as sf object in R

Tags: r, google-earth-engine, sf, well-known-text

When you export a feature collection (as a CSV) from Google Earth Engine, the geometry information is stored in WKT format under the variable `.geo`. The general format for each cell in the vector `.geo` looks something like this:

`{""type"":""Point"",""coordinates"":[-16.129853523180806,12.1466390262208]}`

If I read in the CSV of the feature collection:

`centroidData1 = fread("Tiles/Demo/count_1_plus_rasterdta.csv")`

theoretically, we should be able to use `.geo` to transform `centroidData1` into an `sf` object using the `st_as_sf` function.

```
myCRS= "+proj=longlat + datum=WGS84"
  
centroidPoints1= st_as_sf(centroidData1, 
                          wkt=".geo", 
                          na.fail=T, 
                          crs=coordRS)
```

But when I execute this code, R returns the following error:

```
OGR: Unsupported geometry type
Error in CPL_sfc_from_wkt(x) : OGR error
```

Do I need to reformat the `.geo` variable first? If yes, how?

Comment: tthat's not wkt, that's json

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that! No wonder it wasn't working! Thank you Elio.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe theres a function or parameter in `sf` to parse the json you are trying to pass to the `st_as_sf`; since json is a column of your data, it cannot be parsed directly with `fromJSON`, so you have to parse the column and *then* put it together with the rest of the `data.frame`;

I made a csv with this content:

```
name,quant,geo
a_thing, 1, "{""type"":""Point"",""coordinates"":[-16.129853523180806,12.1466390262208]}"
another_thing, 2, "{""type"":""Point"",""coordinates"":[-16.1299,12.14665]}"
```

and this is the code that transforms your `geo` column to `sf` object:

```
library(sf)
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
 
df = read.csv("gis.csv")
df %>% mutate(geo = map(geo, ~ fromJSON(.) %>% as.data.frame())) %>% 
  unnest(geo) %>% mutate(coord = rep(c("x","y"),2)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = coord, values_from = coordinates) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y")) %>% st_set_crs(4326)
```

prints:

```
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 3 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -16.1299 ymin: 12.14664 xmax: -16.12985 ymax: 12.14665
CRS:            EPSG:4326
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  name          quant type              geometry
* <chr>         <int> <chr>          <POINT [°]>
1 a_thing           1 Point (-16.12985 12.14664)
2 another_thing     2 Point  (-16.1299 12.14665)
```

Comment: Thank you for the support. I tried executing the provided script but received an error: "Error: Evaluation error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file." The geo variable in my csv is saved as a factor variable. Any suggestions on how to address this?

Comment: Update: I cleaned my data so that the geo variable is a character variable. Now I am getting the error: "Error: Column `coord` must be length 200 (the number of rows) or one, not 4". This is odd since I currently am working on a subsetted version of the data with 100 rows (not 200).

Comment: can you do a dput(head(dataframe))? and copy-paste here

Comment: ohhhh I see sorry, `rep(c("x","y"),2)` repeats x y x y; so you should put 100 instead of 2 if your data has 100 rows unnest gives a row for xcoord and a row for ycoord; to make this programmatically use nrow(data.frame)

Comment: Thank you! I tried adjusting for the number of rows, but now I am getting a different error: **Error in pivot_wider(., names_from = coord, values_from = coordinates) : could not find function "pivot_wider"**. I am using all the libraries you listed in your original response: might I need one last R package to execute this? Thank you!!

Comment: `pivot_wider` is a function from `tidyr`, if your tidyr installation is old you should update, it's from november 2019

Answer (score 0):

Using nothing but `fromJSON` and base packages you can do this:

```
> do.call(rbind, Vectorize(fromJSON)(txt=df$geo)[seq(2,nrow(df)*2,by=2)])
```

to get a two-column matrix of coordinates:

```
          [,1]     [,2]
[1,] -16.12985 12.14664
[2,] -16.12990 12.14665
```

In a one-liner:

```
> dfs = st_as_sf(
     cbind(
       df, 
       do.call(
          rbind, 
            Vectorize(fromJSON)(txt=df$geo)[seq(2,nrow(df)*2,by=2)]
            )
       ),
      coords=c("1","2"))
```

which you can then add to your data frame and make an `sf` object.

The only fragility I can see is that it relies on the JSON decoding as two elements, the "type" and the "coordinates", in that order, since it makes a sequence which extracts those elements by numeric index rather than name.

Whatever you do *write yourself a function that does this* so that when all those dependent packages change and break your code you only have the one place to fix it.